# Boot-up Password: Can Ubuntu show the password's characters?

Tags: keyboard, password

I've looked:  no-one has an answer.  My Ubuntu 20.04 box has sda_crypt.  My password is long and my keyboard unreliable.  I can't see my password, only those dots.  How can one have Ubuntu reveal my password's characters as they type?  I am having to spend anywhere from one to twelve attemps, simply due to my keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

> How can one have Ubuntu reveal my password's characters as they type?

A password during boot will never be visible; that is intentional and there is no code in the software to have it echo characters. On the desktop it is possible. And with 2 terminals you can have it echo the "su" password but that is it.

> My password is long

Excellent.

> and my keyboard unreliable.

This looks like you are trying to fix a problem that is not a problem?
I would say: replace your keyboard.

Comment: Are you saying that the only way to make it in software would be to literally modify the sda_crypt module's code?